# Facebook Graph API showing blank page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to use facebook graph api to get the event details of a specific page.But I keep getting a blank page back.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET');

        $session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
        /* make the API call */
        $request = new FacebookRequest(
            $session,
            'GET',
            '/1531904510362357/'
        );
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

        dd($graphObject);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

$session should = new FacebookSession('accesstoken')

Another thing I've learned is that the new api (v2.0+) is very very strict on what is displayed. For example, you can no longer open up someones feed that doesn't also have an access token to your application.

I would go back and read on the permissions and make sure that the correct permissions are set and validated for your application.